Review request for the Empire’s transportation stack?
Intro
Setting
A century or two into the future, humans encounter and ultimately end up joining the Galactic Empire. Humanity, which abandoned the concept of the warp drive with the negative results they got on preliminary research in the early 21st century (this is where the real world and my world’s timelines begin diverging), is surprised to find that the species that seeded the Empire actually figured it out approximately 9,100 years ago, and has been exploring space ever since.
The Empire is fundamentally devoted to forwarding peace and exploration and discovery over war and division across all species, and is a massive multi-civilization entity which imposes a few federal laws that must be followed by all states in a civilization in exchange for access to agriworlds, machine worlds, etc. which produce food and materials in incomprehensible quantities, functionally making the Empire a post-scarcity world where anything can be had within a few days regardless of the price of making it.
The primary function that the Empire serves, however, is to enable other civilizations to engage in space exploration. The bare minimum requirement to join the Empire is the ability of a civilization to build a fleet of functional spaceships (“functional” qualified by the ability to reach certain distance/velocity goals within a reasonable timeframe, as well as carrying a large crew), and after that, the Empire manufactures its unique warp drive and nuclear-thermal engines for installation on any ship under Imperial control. Warp drives in particular are very heavily-controlled since they are quite finicky and, if improperly used (or abused by a malicious actor), can easily turn into deadly weapons.
Under the Empire, and among most sufficiently-advanced civilizations before joining the Empire, space stations and interplanetary colonies are common, but interstellar exploration is very rare since warp drive technology appears to be unique to the seed civilization of the Empire.
In this super society, interplanetary and interstellar journeys are fairly common. The situation of different facilities, research opportunities, people, etc. across the stars means that, on average, an inhabitant of any world at least needs to be able to get from their city to orbit efficiently on a daily basis, and monthly/weekly trips to other celestial bodies are commonplace. The galaxy-trotter or politician or researcher is more likely to need much more frequent such transportation, and oft require weekly interstellar transit.
Technology levels are, generally, pretty futuristic, but nothing is included here that doesn’t explicitly violate physical laws except for perhaps the warp drive. Everything else could, in principle, be built, assuming compact fusion reactors and the like are all successfully invented (there is no reason they can’t be, afaict; it’s just really hard).
Worldbuilding I’m seeking review for
The particular piece of worldbuilding here I am looking to have reviewed is the stack I have set up for space travel. Obviously people on the ground want to go to other ground, so they need a fully-fledged system for getting around their own planetary system/their own star system/between star systems easily. It is common in this world for universities, research facilities, housing, manufacturing, etc. to be located in low orbit if not on another world (feeding tens of billions per planet requires an enormous amount of food production, which although mostly satisfied by Imperial agricultural planets specifically devoted to it, also ends up taking up a lot of the usable land on the home planets of any given civiliation).
So, I have in the course of doing my worldbuilding designed a transportation “stack” from personal-level transportation across distances we 2024-humans would cover with cars to getting into orbit to getting between moons/planets to running between stars with warp drive-equipped ships. Specifically I’m asking for a review of the transportation stack to see if there are gaps in what civilian needs it can satisfy: if this worldbuilding I’ve done so far is sufficient for regular citizens to use on a regular basis, or if there are gaps or inconsistencies or redundancies.

The worldbuilding in question
Ground transportation
Barring humanity and a couple other civilizations (who, understandably, are just about as stingy with their technology with aliens as the Empire is about sharing warp drive tech), compact fusion technology is still not at production scale, despite thousands of years of research; it turns out that the key is highly advanced computing systems, which not all civilizations actually end up needing (you don’t need an RTX 9060 to fly a spaceship).
As such, since fossil fuels and other nonrenewables are specifically outlawed in the Empire due to the constant threat of resource wars they produce, the only allowed personal ground transportation are electric and manually-powered vehicles like EVs and bikes. This turns out not to be a huge change for most civilizations since those capable of interplanetary colonization have all but phased out fossil fuels once it really started damaging their biosphere. Cars and the like are usually used for intra-city transportation when larger infrastructure isn’t present or when cars/the like are just most convenient.
Because of the massive manufacturing infrastructure that machine worlds provide, cars effectively cost nothing. The Empire already heavily-socializes such needs as transportation, and in the event of a car or the like being completely totalled, another one can be made and delivered for the equivalent of around $500, and cheap insurance reduces that to zero in most cases.
Also included under the umbrella of personal transportation are trains, which is a technology that is greatly improved in the future. On many worlds it is very convenient to construct spaceports along the equator for easier/more fuel efficient launches, and space elevators/artificial rings sort of have to be constructed there. However, not everyone lives or works on the equator$^\text{citation needed}$, so magnetically-levitated trains are constructed that can travel extremely fast to get people around quickly, usually going along a particular latitude perpendicular to the equator but also transferring east/west frequently.
On bodies with atmospheres, these trains are limited by the speed of sound so as not to destroy nearby windows and to preserve the sanity of the people who live within earshot of the rails, but on atmosphereless bodies like the Galilean moons and Earth’s moon Luna where that’s not an issue, the trains usually reach orbital velocity and can, at full speed, circumnavigate the world in hours. In such cases, there are no stops (for reasons that will soon be explained); a college student on one side of Europa could get on the train and, at ~1.4 km/s, clear the distance to their home on the other side of the planet in under 4 hours.
Naturally, these trains being very, very large and travelling very, very fast means they carry much kinetic energy. The onboard engines that are used to propel it to such speeds also require fuel, which is equally explosive; due to this, there is a large amount of security implemented aboard trains, armed security officers and constant surveillance in public areas aboard at minimum. In the case of a world having a space elevator, trains can also be made to just do a kilometer-long turn upwards (the train cars all having their interiors rotate on gimbals to maintain the direction of gravity), and trains going up to the geostationary space station from the ground technically counts as international travel, so that’s another purpose security serves.
Small-scale atmospheric/orbital transportation
The next step “up” (or perhaps “out”) is personal and public atmospheric and orbital transportation. Although the more-advanced Imperial civilizations can manage to get some of this infrastructure down themselves, having access to machine worlds certainly helps. While cars and such ground vehicles cost generally under a couple thousand dollars, atmospheric and orbital spaceplanes have taken their place; a personal spaceplane, not substantially different in appearance from a supersonic aircraft like a miniature SR71, equipped with dual-mode nuclear thermal engines and in-orbit life support systems, might cost between $20,000-80,000 equivalent, depending on quality. The standard models that take the place in the price range of low-end sedans and smaller vehicles are typically one- or two-seater with decently powerful engines that have enough fuel to reach orbit and fly around as well as land horizontally at a spaceport or resume aerodynamic flight upon reentry, while more-expensive models have much more powerful engines (sometimes used for racing, where legal and safe) and might have a small seating area/bedroom for long flights in addition to a cockpit.
The dual-mode engines on these ships also function as fuel-less air-breathing engines, working like enhanced nuclear ramjets with some turbine tech to pull in more air at low speeds, so they also work as aircraft; these spaceplanes are functionally SSTOs. In cases like dense metropolises where car congestion can get bad, VTOL personal craft are also used frequently among those who have the facilities to maintain them and the money to afford them, which usually consists of a landing pad and a decent supply of spare parts, plus basic engineering knowledge. Manuals and tutorials are distributed along with the craft on how to perform simple repairs, like if an engine intake gets jammed or if the reactor gets full up with xenon and needs to be cycled or if the landing gear refuses to retract.
Another feature of personal craft is that, on most standard models, they are capable of latching onto trains on atmosphereless bodies. When “catching a train”, instead of putting on a spacesuit to get to the train station (which is necessarily exposed to the vacuum, given that that’s the medium in which the train travels), a civilian would descend from orbit/ascend from their residence, match velocities with the train, and then extend specialized gear that can dock with the train. The ship can then shut off its engines, refuel if the captain is willing to pay a few bucks for the extra hydrogen, and the captain can sit in the warm comfort of the train while waiting for the destination to be near. When it is, the captain activates ventral engines, decouples from the train, and decelerates to regular flying velocity (or boosts up to orbit, which is easy since the train itself moves at orbital speed). Computers onboard the train are given remote control of the ship to pilot it during docking, to avoid biological error costing anyone their lives.
Typically, for very-short-range interplanetary or planet-to-moon or moon-to-moon transits, the nuclear thermal rockets onboard lowest-end cheap personal vessels are usually sufficiently advanced to allow torching most of the way there (exhaust velocity around 7,500 m/s with industry-standard supercritical plutonium reactors, with a typical mass ratio of 2.4 wet/dry), although an immediate stop in orbit to refuel is typically necessary. Some of the more advanced civilizations who have access to compact fusion also use direct fusion drives, which have extremely high efficiency and an exhaust velocity measured in percent of lightspeed (0.3% is the lower end of the spectrum); with such high efficiency, the middle-of-the-road and high-end personal ships are usually capable of torching through interplanetary distances without issue.
Sizing up slightly from personal ships are corvette- and frigate-class ships, which are typically around the size or twice the size of the ISS (as of 2024), respectively. Frigates are typically too large to safely land without specialized equipment; ventral and dorsal engine modules plus additional landing gear might allow a craft as large as a frigate to land safely. Corvette-class ships usually come with this kind of gear, since they are the space equivalent of buses and semi trucks; cargo capacities usually range from a few crew for corvettes that are only slightly larger than a personal craft to several dozen tons for dedicated transports. Frigates tend to take more of the cargo and corvettes more the people; frigate cargo ranges usually go from 100-500 tons and maintain the acceleration and delta-v capabilities of corvettes and personal craft.
For interplanetary-scale transportation of goods and people, corvette-size buses usually work, and at spaceports tickets can be bought to hitch a ride on a corvette into orbit to any station over the planet, a bit cheaper than a 2024 plane ticket. Security is obviously also a concern on public spacecraft, given that any spacecraft is a weapon if you point it in the wrong direction and that space wants to kill you; imagine American fTSA with a 10-minute instructional video on spacesuit and vacuum safety every time. Buses usually arrive twice an hour; larger transports for intra-system or interplanetary journeys are usually a few times a day.
Mass interplanetary transport
For colonization purposes - and, well, sometimes regular purposes - there also needs to be methods of transportation for much larger quantities of people, sometimes in the tens of thousands. Cruiser-class ships, which are typically around a kilometer in length, are specifically designed to manage large amounts of people on long journeys. The price to board is that of a plane ticket at least, but it’s essentially an ocean liner in space; tickets come with complementary food, beverage, entertainment, lodging onboard, etc. for everyone on the journey. Usually for closer destinations that are only a few hours away by torching, a fleet of frigates will be used instead, but for longer trips that will start to grind people down when they have to sit for days or weeks in a glorified metal box without anything to do, cruiser groups are set up. They’re the size of mansions on the inside; around a hundred decks with over a thousand meters square on the inside for each, there’s plenty of room for everyone involved.
Cruisers are not capable of landing. Aircraft, as it turns out, don’t work when they’re that large. Cruisers are always assembled and used in space, typically docking with space stations to accept and deliver passengers and crew. Standard torchship abilities included: continuous 1-g burn to the halfway point to accelerate, continuous 1-g burn to the destination to decelerate. Amenities like food/water/equipment for entertainment included, the cruiser can also typically carry around a few dozen tons of cargo. Food and water are rationed for the journey (with a 50% safety factor, so a cargo bay failure or a bunch of weirdly-hungry passengers doesn’t mean instant death), with usually a decent three meals a day, but entertainment is constant and the cruisers maintain a constant data-stream back to the origin and to the destination for communications.
Cruisers, when not in use carrying passengers, can also carry a very large amount of cargo. Up to 1,500 tons at the most for interplanetary missions, dropping all the water recycling and food reclamation and entertainment systems adds a ton of spare weight to the craft. When transporting parts or supplies or even smaller ships to other worlds, cruisers are typically used with specialized designs where the various crew cabins, onboard parks, bathrooms, etc. etc. etc. are all carved out and replaced with docking ports for other spacecraft. Even the captain is replaced with a remotely-operated computer, which has its route pre-programmed and has basic obstacle avoidance so that it can deliver the payload safely.
Civilians are typically advised not to do anything suspicious or otherwise-untoward while aboard cruisers; not for the benefit of the other passengers, but because surveillance is constant. Aboard frigates, you usually have a small tight-knit crew who all know each other and are good friends, none of whom would ever be expected to do anything to get everyone killed. On cruisers, you have a large crew of a few hundred, plus thousands of civilians, any of whom could decide for some reason to sabotage the engines and leave the cruiser drifting in interplanetary space, which would doom everyone if someone couldn’t come rescue them immediately. To prevent the events of a particular popular mobile game from taking place, security cameras are everywhere and everyone is under constant surveillance. On occasion, the security systems catch criminals trying to escape the law or transporting contraband.
Interstellar transport
Frigate-class ships and larger can be equipped with warp drives, which are devices designed by the Imperial seed civ that are capable of doing a special manipulation of spacetime to create a causal path through space that allows for FTL travel. The devices are highly sensitive to gravitational fields, so typically aren’t used in orbit of a planet except in military/emergency circumstances, and usually require a very large amount of power to continuously operate, but they can immediately kick a spacecraft up to tens or hundreds of times lightspeed for smaller and weaker drives, or even thousands or millions of times lightspeed for the bigger and better ones. Each warp drive consists of a “containment region”, a volume of space usually fitted to the spaceship itself via an external skin layer, which when filled with energy in the appropriate configuration results in warp field production. The drive itself is usually not easily removable from the ship.
There are several varieties of drives, each categorized based on the mass-energy configuration required to produce the “warp field” within which certain FTL vectors are allowed. The simplest - and also most powerful, and also most finicky - is the dark energy drive, which has an Einstein tensor of zero. According to the Einstein field equations (EFEs),
$$G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$$
for the Einstein tensor $G$, the metric tensor $g$, the stress-energy tensor $T$, a small constant $\kappa$ and a smaller constant $\Lambda$. The dark energy drive having zero Einstein curvature means that, although it doesn’t contain any energy proper, requires energy densities that are slightly less than that of the vacuum due to the cosmological constant; as such, quantum effects must be leveraged to produce negative energy densities from the point of view of someone embedded in spacetime. This is to counteract or, colloquially, “clear out” the dark energy in the spacetime to reduce the vacuum energy, thus producing the desired warp field. This works more efficiently than any other model (there is an in-world a mathematical proof of this, in fact), but any electromagnetic perturbation causes the DE drive to collapse; it’s only ever used as a novelty item.
The downside to DE drives: they require negative energy density, which is extremely difficult to maintain and has size limitations associated with it (around 600 meters is as large as a DE drive can be). The upside: the maximum negative energy required is small, so an arbitrarily-powerful warp field can be produced with any DE drive. Ships equipped with DE drives, although sort of like the USS Enterprise in their likelihood to spontaneously fail and need the plasma coils to be recalibrated, can jump across the entire galaxy instantaneously, assuming that the appropriate warp drive parameters can be calculated.
The more-standard configurations are exponential and polynomial drives, so named for the patterns with which their energy density falls off inside the drive’s containment region. They require megawatts of energy to operate, and as such only ships large enough to have embedded nuclear reactors, like frigate-class and larger, are capable of maintaining them. The most common is the quadratic-falloff drive, with power requirements around 100-200 watts per lightspeed per cubic meter of enveloped space, although fancier cubic-falloff drives are more expensive at around 500-750 W/c/m3 and quartic-falloff drives at around 0.7-1 kW/c/m3 drives are generally easier to use due to their improved simplicity and tunability. Linear-falloff drives are quite complex to use, but require barely any power at around 5 W/c/m3, and are generally used on high-end cruisers. Again,  nothing smaller than a frigate has the power capacity to run a non-DE warp drive.
Navigating warped space
While warp drives are already semi-magical in that they can produce warp fields with low energy densities, navigating through warped spacetime is incredibly difficult. In the vacuum case of otherwise-flat spacetime, it’s easy enough and a computer can manage it, but in the nonlinear case of navigating into/out of star systems, and especially through interstellar space which is fraught with gravitational radiation and dust clouds and gamma ray bursts that can interfere with drive technology, there isn’t a good closed-form solution. The Empire was, in fact, founded by the Empress who, almost ten thousand years ago, was born with a genetic disorder that caused part of her brain to grow into an extremely-regular and highly-manipulable structure that acted as the most powerful computer any civilization has ever seen. With basic information about the interstellar landscape, the Empress can singlehandedly produce desirable warp drive parameters that will safely navigate the void.
The Empress, who is obviously a person of great importance, is kept very far away on the Palace World of Prima Luna, halfway across the galaxy from humans around Sol. Fortunately, FTL communication is possible via the same avenue as FTL travel - the construction of stable geons out of warp fields, which self-accelerate as they reduce in energy over time, including past lightspeed - so when a warp drive needs to be activated to bring a starship across the galaxy, a request is sent through a large relay space station to the Palace World, where the Empress solves the EFEs for the specific scenario and returns the result to the querent. Having long since uploaded her mind to a supercomputer array, the Empress is more than capable of handling billions of requests per second; however, the relay stations are key since they contain the massive geonic arrays that are needed to communicate with the Palace World over hundreds of lightyears. Appropriately-equipped ships can do direct communication, but the geonic arrays required to do that are often as large as the ship itself and it’s not practical. Instead, a small radio dish-sized geonic comms system is equipped along with any warp drive, and the relay handles communication with the Palace World.
Yes, that does mean that it is extremely important that the relays never fail, given that such an event would mean that all warp drives that previously relied on it are now dead weight. Yes, that means that relays are usually defended with “extreme prejudice” and regarded by the Empire as military-importance installations.
As a “stack”
Most of these modes of transportations, barring personal craft, are all directly maintained by the Empire. To ensure its citizens’ abilities to get where they need to go, it is critical that this infrastructure is maintained, especially in space where failing infrastructure is synonymous with death. Corvettes, frigates, personal craft, cars, etc. that are owned personally must be paid for, but the Empire foots the bill for anything intended for public use. This being a post-scarcity world, “paying” for it mostly involves just paying people to continue to maintain the machine worlds and the transportation infrastructure, which can still be expensive even if the parts to build the ship are $0.01 a piece.
These socialized transportation systems, then, are like a software stack but for transportation: each layer builds on the next, so that the Imperial citizens can safely and efficiently get anywhere they need to go.
Review request
Restated: Specifically I’m asking for a review of the transportation stack to see if there are gaps in what civilian needs it can satisfy: if this worldbuilding I’ve done so far is sufficient for regular citizens to use on a regular basis, or if there are gaps or inconsistencies or redundancies. Are there any gaps here? That is, is this system sufficient for the average civilian, who might take interplanetary/interstellar journeys frequently and requires daily transportation to/from orbit and all over the planet, also keeping in mind those who need to travel farther/more frequently?

Disclaimer: This is, to my knowledge, the inaugural RMIQ asked on this stack since the policy was approved on Meta. There were other recent questions retroactively marked as RMIQ like this one, because they are good examples of RMIQ, but afaik this is the first that is being newly asked. I hope I’m asking this right!
I tried my best to follow the given guidelines:
Complete and Detailed - this is, in my opinion, quite detailed worldbuilding.
There is Only One Question - I’ve just asked for one review piece, if I’m not mistaken.
Goals and Conditions Required: I’ve got the actual review request written clearly a couple times here; I hope it’s sufficient.
Scope - I’m focusing on just the transportation aspects of the Empire here, which I hope is tight enough a scope considering how much wider it could have been.
Edits - no edits from me are coming except clarification/typing mistake corrections.
Abuse - this is my first RMIQ question, so I think that’s a given.

We (controlgroup specifically) may have just uncovered a weakness in the [review-my-idea] model. Perhaps some sort of brevity and focus constraint needs taking into account.

I was considering that... This post is a fair bit shorter/around the same length as the one JBH cited as a good example so that's the sort of length I shot for. Good learning opportunity, at least; means we know that this length is probably a bit too long. (The cited good example vs mine, it's Frog's 4,300 words vs. my 4,000, for reference, if you/the others want to institute a soft word limit.)

I thought that one was way too long. I also thought the premise was flawed from the start, but the answers caught that - that could have been caught with a much shorter, less technical version of the question in that one's case. I think your premise seems OK, personally. I've a criticism (or additional suggestion) re structure/strength and scale considerations, but wait to see what others say.

Alright, thanks for the feedback. Perhaps the live data we get from RMIQs that show up should be put somewhere so we can adjust it as time goes by (for example, that 4,000 words is too long)? And yeah, that sounds like an answer I'm going to get, assuming I do get any.

@controlgroup - although I havent read it yet, the discussion around RMIQ was that the idea needed to be fully formed (so as not to fall afoul of brainstorming) - and so I would expect that these type of questions would be in the longer form.

That's what I was thinking too @TheDemonLord. I think EDP has a point, though, there probably is an upper limit on how long we want it to be. My post was on the shorter end and is still pretty long (although a fair bit longer than a regular post).

@Escapeddentalpatient. Brevity will always be at risk (and, after all, people can choose to skip the question), but I believe we should expect the first half-dozen questions to be a bit rocky as we iron out the details. ControlGroup, I think the scope of your question can be narrowed. It's an artform to write concise questions. No transportation system is perfect and no one transportation system will ever be appropriate for evey kind of civilian transport (i.e., luxury liners vs. bulk transport. Thus, a better focused goal for the review would be in order.

Oh, and thanks, @controlgroup, for paticipating with this with a thick skin. The first few tests of this new tag isn't calling your idea or your question ugly so much as it's calling the process the tag embodies ugly - but it can be hard to see the difference when you're likely to be collateral damage. Thanks.

@JBH That's why I made the post, trying to get RMIQ stuff all worked out. Always happy to help :)

You done good controlgroup! The only edit I would suggest (and this might be addressed in Meta as well) is that querents somehow discriminate between text that is vital to the question itself and text that is cool & descriptive & can safely be ignored. Just a quick example: does the fact that a student living on the Moon can hop on a train and get half way around the planet in 4 hours fundamentally make or break the question? If the answer is no, then it should either be removed entirely or indented or set apart from the text that is. All in all, great first RMIQ!

Also great feedback, thank you! Definitely going to be a highlight of what RMIQs we have going forward given that I think there's some consensus already that they're going to be a bit longer than normal posts.

I added the worldbuilding process tag because this kind of review is most definitely a piece of worldbuilding process!

Personally, I would split this into a few regimes:
Planetside

Medium density (Earth-like). I can make a pretty good guess at your nationality based on your focus on cars. There are numerous issues with car-centric urban development, which I won't rehash here. Personally, I'm not convinced the metros, buses, and trams of the next few centuries will be that different to today's, but you might be more creative. Personal spaceplanes would probably be restricted on these worlds, because of the risk of accident (even if flown by AI). Cargo ships for bulk transportation may well still see use.
High density (highly urbanised worlds). The above but much moreso. The engineering cost of a pole-equator maglev would be so egregious I'm not convinced they would beat out supersonic aircraft except on these worlds. I can see high-density worlds not allowing orbit-ground travel except for VIPs - cargo and normals go through space elevators. This way, they can shoot any potential frigate-wielding terrorist on sight.
Low density (colonies and rural planets). Cars are good. Light aircraft and helicopters will be useful here too, and so may watercraft. I can see traditional trains being useful for transporting fertiliser, non-perishable food, and anything else not in a hurry, across the planet.

Space
Looks pretty good to me :). Your civilian ships all use military classes, which is odd, but it does aid understanding.
If people need to travel regularly to other planets or star systems, I think you underestimate the scale of transport needed. Look at the size of the trains that run between major European, East Asian, or Indian cities. You would need a very large fleet of bus-sized corvettes to meet that capacity.
FTL
I would encourage you to think about solving FTL equations in terms of computational complexity. For example, if ship size has little bearing on how much effort the Empress needs to plot a course, I would expect star-liners to get very, very large, concentrating travel on a few key routes. If it takes the same amount of Empress-Time to send a cruiser of thousands as a corvette of eighty, a ticket on the corvette would be very expensive. If Empress-Time increased with the square of distance, then most travel will comprise of short hops and long layovers. Only VIPs will be able to take direct trips.
On a personal note - cameras, security, training videos, armed guards everywhere, any hint of suspicious behaviour scrutinised - would I hate to travel in your empire.

Pleasure, hobby and niche vehicles
ATVs, skidoos, jetskis.
Think of how varied life must be for such a galactic empire, different worlds, climates etc.
Simply having a car or a bike for functional travel is one thing, but what about say a boat purely for Fishing?
Maybe you are an Avid hunter and regularly go to different worlds and hunt? Needing a specialized vehicle or boat or hovercraft or aircraft to hunt from.
Then things like Hobby vehicles: the example that sprung to mind was James Cameron and his love of submersibles.
For people who have large amounts of land - things like Tractors or other agricultural or terraforming vehicles.
There's so much more than just point A to point B.
Racing!!
I don't know about other species, but we humans are infamous for our love of speed and racing anything with wheels and/or an engine.

Your citizens are missing the freedom to space travel wherever they want to go
If you were to DDOS the super computer empress, the network would crash. While billions of requests can be served, there is always a limit. If the empress is overwhelmed, the whole space travel network goes down. As such, there would have to be an authority to decide which requests are valid and allowed to reach the main processing center. This authority would have unilateral control of who goes where and when. They would have a monopoly on trade and passenger routes. You wanna take a ship from A to B? You better hope it benefits the empire.
Where are the smugglers?
Unlicensed commerce is an integral part of an economy. If there are taxes, then there are people trying to evade them. Whats ships would they use? How far can they go? You can bet there will be several factions trying to solve the magical equation of space travel at all times. Duplicating the power the empress holds would be worth, well, an empire.

Ooooooh - excellent point on Smuggling and the Black economy!
